# Sum all values in CSV

Tags: python, csv, sum

I have a CSV file with `0`s and `1`s and need to determine the sum total of the entire file. The file looks like this when opened in ExCel:

```
0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1
0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1
0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0
0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1
```

Using this script I can sum the values of each row and they print out in a single column:

```
import csv 

import numpy as np

path = r'E:\myPy\one_zero.csv' 

infile = open(path, 'r')

with infile as file_in: 
    fin = csv.reader(file_in, delimiter = ',') 
    for line in fin: 
        print line.count('1')
```

I need to be able to sum up the resulting column, but my experience with this is mild. Looking for suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: I've gotten it to go over each line and count how many times '1' occurs, but this is not summing I believe.  It can give me a column with the frequency values, but haven't been able to add up that column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
path = r'E:\myPy\one_zero.csv' 
infile = open(path, 'r')
answer = 0
with infile as file_in: 
   fin = csv.reader(file_in, delimiter = ',') 
   for line in fin: 
      a = line.count(1)
      answer += a
print answer
```

Example:

```
answer = 0
lines = [[1, 0, 0, 1],[1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,1]]
for line in lines:
   a = line.count(1)
   answer += a
print answer
7
```

One possible error is you used:

```
line.count('1')
```

vs

```
line.count(1)
```

looking for a string instead of a numeric

Comment: This DID work once I copied/pasted... had error when I typed it out at first.

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than just 1's and 0's map to int and sum all rows:

```
with open( r'E:\myPy\one_zero.csv') as f:
     r = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ',') 
     count = sum(sum(map(int,row)) for row in r)
```

Or just count the 1's:

```
with open( r'E:\myPy\one_zero.csv' ) as f:
     r = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ',')
     count = sum(row.count("1") for row in r)
```

Just use `with open(r'E:\myPy\one_zero.csv')`, you don't need to and should not  open and then pass the file handle to with.

Comment: @kwikstrom, yep. use `with` to open the file as in my answer.

Comment: The help is very much appreciated

Comment: no worries. What do you want to do with the data , I see you have imported numpy also

Comment: Largely for statistics and numpy is supposedly best for that (I've been hearing lately and used it before).  I have csv files with only integer values (no description text at all), ultimately for land information.

Comment: you can actually load data straight from a file into arrays using numpy

Comment: I'd tried that but failed.  Wanted arrays to start with.  Suggestions to get csv into array?

Comment: `arr = np.genfromtxt(r'E:\myPy\one_zero.csv',delimiter=",")` If you want the sum of each  column `print(sum(arr))`. There is also `pandas.read_csv`

Answer (score 0):

Why use the CSV module at all?  You have a file full of 0s, 1s, commas and newlines.  Just open the file, read() it and count the 1s:

```
>>> with open(filename, 'r') as fin: print fin.read().count('1')
```

That should get you what you want, no?

Comment: This also did the job.  Thanks

Comment: No problem.  Just note that this only works for a file consisting solely of 1s and 0s.  Any more complexity and you would have to go the way others have suggested.

Comment: It also reads the whole file into memory which is not always a good idea